# Get mean out of dataframe with same values (id) in row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i want to calculate the mean values based on the id out of a data frame like this:

```
id  |  value
1      100
2      200
3      100
1      100
1      100
3      200
2      300
```

that's what i've coded so far:

```
ids <- unique(df$id)
for(i in ids){
  ...
}
```

how am i able to call only the values with each id to calculate the mean?

outcome (mean) of the example values above should be: 1 = 100, 2 = 250, 3 = 150

Comment: Just do `aggregate(value ~ id, df1, mean)`

Comment: thanks a lot!! It worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the ID column and then easily calculate a mean or any other aggregate metric:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_summary <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(id_mean = mean(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tapply`:

```
tapply(df$value, df$id, mean)
```